# Пропуск элемента и переход к следующему элементу в цикле For

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте.

Есть список `List<WebElement>` с динамическими элементами которые меняют свою ширину каждые два дня. Их количество так же меняется, поэтому прогнал через цикл `for`, чтобы кликнуть на все по-очереди.

Все работало до тех пор, пока два элемента не приняли ширину значения `0`. Selenium Webdriver выдал ошибку:

> Element is not clickable at point…

Теперь мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при встрече с таким элементом, Selenium пропускал этот элемент (на который он не может кликнуть) в цикле и переходил к следующему элементу, на который можно кликнуть (в данном случае это следущий элемент имеющий ширину больше 0).

Ниже привел код Java, с которым я пыталася работать, но пропустить некликаемый элемент и перейти к другому элементу не получается. Помогите советом.

Спасибо!

```
for (i = 0; i < elements.size(); i ++) {
    elements.get(i).getSize().getWidth();
    if (elements.get(i).getSize().getWidth() == 0) {
        elements.get(i.next()).click();
    }
    elements.get(i).click();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так

```
for (i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    if (elements.get(i).getSize().getWidth() <= 0) {
        continue;
    }
    elements.get(i).click();
}
```

Оператор `continue` начинает следующий проход цикла, минуя оставшееся тело цикла

---

**UPD** в условии указано **"<= 0"** т.к. поля с отрицательной шириной тоже не кликабельные

Answer (score 2):

Пробежаться по всем элементам, отфильтровав с учётом нулевой длины, можно так:

```java
elements.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getSize().getWidth() > 0)
    .forEach(WebElement::click);
```